# Why does Flex Debugging stop working after a while in Firefox 6 with breakpoints?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, timeout, firefox6

I was currently working on a flex application with debugging set to Firefox 6.  I set a breakpoint and was checking some variables... next thing I know the browser says "flash player crashed."  How do I set it up so breakpoints work for an extended period of time?

Comment: Why are you asking if you found the fix, even if it is useful information? You should at least post the answer in a different post and mark it as correct.

Comment: I don't have a high enough "stack rating" so I can't answer my question for another 7 hours.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just open firefox and type "**about:config**" - scroll down to **dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs** - enter "**-1**"

[image: Just open firefox and type "about:config" - scroll down to dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs - enter "-1"]

Comment: Dude, this is most awesome! Thx!